# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() error assistance needed

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of code for my code that when the user inputs 7 digits it multiplies the digits by 3 and 1 respectively. Here is the code;

[image]

When it goes to check if the user has entered 7 digits it gives me this error:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: No, that is a link to a picture of the code. Paste the code here, as text.

Comment: Please post your code here to get help and ask an specific question.

Comment: Not related to Code, but i got the same error the reason was function name was min(). As min() is the function it was throwing error so make sure to note this aswell. Hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 17):

**Abstract:**

The reason why you are getting this `error` message is because you are trying to call a method on an `int` type of a variable. This would work if would have called `len()` function on a `list` type of a variable. Let's examin the two cases:

**Fail:**

```
num = 10

print(len(num))
```

The above will produce an error similar to yours due to calling `len()` function on an `int` type of a variable;

**Success:**

```
data = [0, 4, 8, 9, 12]

print(len(data))
```

The above will work since you are calling a function on a `list` type of a variable;

Answer (score 9):

Well, maybe an `int` does not posses the `len` attribute in Python like your error suggests?

Try:

```
len(str(numbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it is the problem of using `len()` for an integer value.
does not posses the len attribute in Python.

Error as:I will give u an example:

```
number = 1
print(len(number))
```

Instead of use ths,

```
data = [1,2,3,4]
print(len(data))
```

Comment: `print(len(number))` in your case