# Using Django validators with admin - TypeError: "object of type 'int' has no len()"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

so I have an eCommerce customer-facing app with a Django Admin interface. I want employees who will be using the admin to be able to create users. The problem is the custom regex validation I built in applies to the customer-facing side only, and when an employee wants to create a new user using the admin, my use of Django Validators throws an error when attempting to create the user.

I was wondering if (1) there was a way to reuse my UserManager class (inherited from models.Manager) which handles the customer-side validation, with Django admin also. If not, then (2) if I was to rely on Django Validators how could I clean up the code as to not throw errors like:

```
TypeError: "object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I've done a little homework trying to figure this out and found this thread: [TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() error assistance needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204529/typeerror-object-of-type-int-has-no-len-error-assistance-needed)

This basically explains the error being thrown for this example is because it's trying to call len() on an int instead of a list. What I don't get is why don't I get this same error on the customer-facing side when a user signs himself up?

At any rate, I can't figure out how to implement the solution given how I set up my UserManager. I'm not using Django Forms and have tried fooling around with some of the clean methods, but am also trying not to repeat myself by reusing the validation I already wrote in the UserManager.

Here is my code, thanks for any help!

### **models.py**

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def validation(self, postData, error_validation):
    errors = {}
    if error_validation == 'register':
        if not NAME_REGEX.match(postData['first_name']):
            errors['first_name'] = "First name can only contain letters."
        if not NAME_REGEX.match(postData['last_name']):
            errors['last_name'] = "Last name can only contain letters."
        elif User.objects.filter(email=postData['email']):
            errors['email'] = "Email already being used."
        elif len(postData['password']) < 8:
            errors['password'] = "Password must contain 8 or more characters."
        elif not postData['password'] == postData['confirm_password']:
            errors['password'] = "Both passwords must match!"
    if error_validation == 'login':
        user = User.objects.filter(email=postData['email'])
        if not user or not bcrypt.checkpw(postData['password'].encode(), user[0].password.encode()):
            errors['user_login'] = "Invalid credentials."
    return errors


class User(models.Model):
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob             = models.DateField()
    address         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    zipcode         = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(5), MaxLengthValidator(10)])
    phone           = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(10), MaxLengthValidator(10)])
    email           = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    password        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at      = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at      = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    objects         = UserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `MinLengthValidator` and `MaxLengthValidator` on the IntegerFields, which will try to apply len() function on the integers. That's why you got this kind of error. You can change your `zipcode` and `phone` attributes to CharField, or just remove the validators.

Comment: I would also add that zip codes and phone numbers are not integers, but _strings_ of numbers. Integers are best for math operations, not representations of data.

Comment: Touche. I'll probably end up changing to charfield eventually. I suppose I was just lazy in using regex with charfield to filter just numbers, and stubborn that I still thought I could make it work my way.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that **CharField doesn't have a min_length attribute.**

So just as an ill-advised alternative, instead of using Min/MaxLengthValidator, you can use Min/MaxValueValidator Min/MaxValueValidator. What's cool is you can subclass the validators to handle custom error messaging:

**models.py**

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator


class ZipcodeMaxValueValidator(MaxValueValidator):
    message = ("AWWW YEA ERROR!!")

class User(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(99999), ZipcodeMaxValueValidator(99999)]
```